# Trying to add a subdomain, but it keeps pointing to my main directory

Tags: apache2

I've been searching all over for a similar situation as mine, but nothing I can find has helped.  It seems that my .conf file is correct, and the subdomain partially works (I have it set to log to a different access.log, and that works properly), but it uses the wrong directory.

Here is my subdomain.conf from the sites-available folder:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName beta.subdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.beta.subdomain.com

    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/django_projects_BETA

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/beta/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/beta/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am attempting to access a random URL on the beta subdomain. My beta directory has Django's debug mode turned on, so I should see the debug output on beta and a simple "Not Found" on the main.  I am seeing the "Not Found" page on the beta subdomain which is how I know it's accessing the original directory and not the one I defined for the beta subdomain.

Has anyone come across a similar issue before?  Is there anything else I could try to get the Virtual Host to work completely?

Comment: You _did_ restart the http server after making modifications to the configuration?

Comment: Yes.  I've tried restarting multiple times to no avail.